# Why don't $\rm SO(10)/Spin(10)$ or larger GUTs permit electron-pair decay?

Tags: conservation-laws, group-theory, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

$\rm Spin(10)$ unifies all left-handed fermions and anti-fermions, and all right-handed fermions and anti-fermions.  And its Pati-Salam subgroup unifies quarks with leptons (SU(4)) and complements SU(2)<sub>L</sub> with SU(2)<sub>R</sub>.

And $\rm Spin(10)$ includes $\rm SU(5)$'s $u_L^α\to \bar{u}_L^{\bar β}+X^{\bar γ}$ and even introduces $d_L^α\to \bar{d}_L^{\bar β}+X^{\bar γ}$.  So why doesn't Spin(10) introduce anything like $e_L\to \bar{e}_L + X_{???}$?

An intermediate answer is such vertices also change color, which includes [lilac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pati%E2%80%93Salam_model).  But in that case, why doesn't Spin(10) introduce constant-color ones like $u_L^α\to \bar{u}_L^{\bar α}+X_{???}$?  Is it because this would require flipping three [indices](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-guts.pdf)?  Do any larger GUTs do so, even non-viable ones?

Comment: Electrons can't decay into positrons, because positrons already have the same mass as electrons.

Comment: @knzhou Nope, doesn't apply before SSB. Neutrinos can become quarks via Spin(10) bosons, e.g. $ν\to \bar d + Y^-$.

Comment: @knzhou Also up & anti-up quarks have the same post-SSB mass too, yet SU(5) and Spin(10) still contain $u_L^α\to \bar{u}_L^{\bar β}+X^{\bar γ}$.

Comment: No, you're saying that these vertices are allowed by the gauge symmetry. That doesn't mean the processes are allowed by energy-momentum conservation.

Comment: @knzhou  I didn't ask about trivial energy conservation.  I asked about group symmetry.  Energy conservation is irrelevant; imagine ultrarelativistic initial mass-energy if you have to.

Comment: @knzhou And no, $n\to 35 n$ is not possible in the Standard Model.  Please read the question.

Comment: Energy conservation is relevant, and just saying that the particle has a high initial energy doesn't change that. After all, you can always just analyze the decay process in the rest frame of the decaying particle.

Comment: @knzhou No, it isn't: one or more particles can be virtual. I asked for elaboration why Spin(10) symmetry doesn't permit this vertex.  I didn't ask what "four-momentum conservation" is.

Comment: @knzhou And no, you cannot analyze an ultrarelativistically colliding electron-pair in a reference frame where both have zero momentum.